# PGP help - primary user IDs not showing up on server

Tags: encryption, pgp, gnupg

So I have two email addresses, personal and work, and I want both to be user IDs for one PGP public key. I'm not super techy so I am going to try to be overly clear here. I am using Mac OS. In GPG keychain, it says both email addresses are user IDs but that my personal email address is the primary. However, when I type in my email addresses in the MIT PGP keyserver, only my work email/user ID shows up. How is this possible? I have pushed key to server again multiple times and nothing changes.

Comment: Without more information, we cannot help you. I am also voting to migrate this question to [su].

Comment: Some times it takes a while until the changes are propagated on the key server. How long ago did you push for the last time? Could you share you pgp finger print, then we can have a look at the public part of your ID. Also try to FIRST refresh and THEN update and AFTERWARDS push to the server. Maybe the server discards the changes because the where made to an older version of you ID.